# Spring "The prefix "tx" for element "tx:annotation-driven" is not bound."

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm getting the error above on my "tx:annotation-driven" line, but I've declared the namespace at the top of the beans file, why is the following XML causing this error?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/assessme" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="assessme" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="assessme" />
    </beans:bean>

     <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>org.assessme.com.entity.User</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="org.assessme.com.controller.entity" />
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.assessme.com." />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="defaultViews">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <beans:property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Just like your other xmlns: definations, you need one for xmlns:tx

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
```

Comment: awesome - thanks, this is a bit bizarre but after adding this, now none of my MVC @requestmapping in my controllers work and my application just 404's as the dispatcherservlet says it can't map anything.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I don't know spring webframework well, but most probably because I don't think having xmlns:tx is the source of your problems.<br/> May be you forgot to include the spring transactions + AOP libraries in your WAR.

Answer (score 26):

You may look [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html) for further information:

> The tx tags deal with configuring all of those beans in Spring's
>   comprehensive support for transactions. These tags are covered in the
>   chapter entitled Chapter 9, Transaction management.
>
> ...
>
> In the interest of completeness, to use the tags in the tx schema, you
>   need to have the following preamble at the top of your Spring XML
>   configuration file; the emboldened text in the following snippet
>   references the correct schema so that the tags in the tx namespace are
>   available to you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

   <!-- <bean> definitions goes here -->

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must introduce the annotation `tx` to your project, you must install them, dont use the `xmlns`, it doesn't work correcty, I see that you develop with annotation, its good practice and use this,

http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx

http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd

Answer (score 0):

For the former solution doesn't help try this put it at the top make sure that you do not forget any **xsi:schemaLocation**.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"></beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```